# Dense least-squares with millions of variables

Tags: linear-solver, reference-request

Suppose $X$ is a dense $m\times n$ data matrix and we seek to find $w$  by approximately iterating least-squares filter equation:

$$w = w - \mu (X'X)^{-1}X'(Xw-b)$$

What are known approaches for $10^9<m<\infty$ and $n\approx 10^6$?

This setting [comes up](https://machine-learning-etc.ghost.io/preconditioners-in-optimization/) in Machine Learning and people tend to invent their own techniques for approximate pseudo-inverse of $X$, which in practice has low [stable-rank](https://nickhar.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/lecture-15-low-rank-approximation-of-matrices/), without referencing scientific computing literature.

For instance KFAC [method](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05671) addresses large $n$ by writing $x\approx a\otimes b$ and using this factorization to approximate $(X'X)^{-1}\approx (A'A)^{-1}\otimes (B'B)^{-1}$. Making this update numerically stable requires considerable tweaking.

Any literature pointers appreciated!

**Edit Jul 19** [crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426670/preconditioners-for-ax-y-that-rely-on-hierarchical-statistical-modeling) on mathoverflow

Comment: How do you store the matrix X?  It has at least 10^15 elements (m=10^9, n=10^5), so even at half-precision (2 bytes per entry), this would take 2*10^15 bytes or 2000 terabytes (or 4000 terabytes at single precision or 8000 terabytes at double precision.)  Your problem is ridiculously over-determined- it would probably make sense to work with a much smaller sample of data.

Comment: $X$ is too large to fit into memory, so update is typically performed by using a random subset of $k$ rows during each step

Comment: As a concrete example for size, JFT-300m dataset has 300 million example. Taking youtube frames as examples nets trillions of images. Compression and delivery of these datasets involve a lot of engineering

Comment: Maybe you can try to factor it (like using a SVD), sometimes only a few factors are needed to provide a good description of the matrix content. But definitely, factoring the matrix $X$ into something simpler is likely needed.

Comment: Large $m$ is easy to deal with, just take subset of data and reuse same algs as before. But large $n$ is a problem. I can't SVD the whole thing, so how do I break it into smaller problems? Doing SVD on blocks? Hierarchically? I'm guessing someone has invented algorithms for this scale already, I just need to find their names

Comment: I think what you are looking for is randomized numerical linear algebra, and randomized SVD in particular. See, for example: https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/01/17/randomized-svd/

Comment: @AmitHochman thanks for the tip, looks like Tropp recently had a follow-up that uses those ideas specifically for fitting large dense linear systems -- https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.02820